# Running a javascript from an html button

Tags: javascript, html

I have an external javascript that I need to run on a button click. How would I go about doing that?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://tracking.somedomain.com/include.js?
domain=www.somedomain.com'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' >
if(typeof sWOTrackPage=='function')sWOTrackPage();
</script>
```

I need this to run on the click of an html button. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean, I need `this` to run? Did that script add anything to the global namespace? Can you provide an example of where you got those docs from?

Answer (score 3):

Pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('theIDofYourButton').onclick = function() {
    //your code here
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#theIDofYourButton').click(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: the `onclick` attribute will do too.

Comment: Does `getElementById()` work with a leading `#` in the value?

Comment: Thank you for drawing attention to that.  I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

```
// Assuming the button has an id of 'btn':
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    // Your code.
    //

});
```

If you need support for older browsers, check out [the older way to register event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners).

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:
HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Do" id="doer" />
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("doer").onclick = function() {
    if(typeof sWOTrackPage=='function') sWOTrackPage();
}
```

The latter Javascript isn't practice-perfect, but that's not really the point here.

If you have any questions about how this was done, please ask away in the comments

Answer (score -1):

Simplest answer. Use the onclick attribute on your HTML button

Comment: True, but it doesn't separate content from presentation, and judging from the apparent need of tracking, this might be a complex site in need of an MVC

Comment: [This is a terrible idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0/9440536#9440536).

Comment: Sometimes simple is the best solution

Comment: Not for this setup, it isn't.